# Switching to Emacs from Textmate and can't figure out how to autocreate a TODO/FIXE list from source files

Tags: emacs, comments, todo

I am making the switch to emacs from Textmate and really want to find an easy way to find all the TODOs and FIXMEs in my Rails projects. In Textmate there is a TODO bundle.  In Vim there is the tasklist.  What is the equivalent in emacs?  Is this done with a grep?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [this](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/fixme-mode.el) might be a good place to start. :)

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan Rockway's [eproject](https://github.com/jrockway/eproject) is a lightweight project management package that has that functionality. You'll have to do some configuration to define the files in your project. After that, you can use `M-x eproject-todo` to find all the TODOs and FIXMEs.

It also has implementations of find-file and switch-buffer that restricts the choices to itmes in the project.